# How can I abstract IRepository<Invoice> and IRepository<Estimate> as IRepository<SalesTransaction>?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following class structure

```
public abstract class SalesTransaction
{

}

public class Invoice : SalesTransaction
{

}

public class Estimate : SalesTransaction
{

}

public interface IRepostory<T>
{
    T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T item);
    T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, bool disableTracking = false);
}
```

Can I somehow abstract `IRepository<Invoice>` and `IRepository<Estimate>` by casting it to `IRepository<SalesTransaction>`?

```
IRepository<Invoice> invoiceRepository = /* Create instance */;
IRepository<SalesTransaction> salesTransaction = invoiceRepository;
```

The code above doesn't compile. Is there a workaround to get it to compile and work?

Comment: Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Comment: And this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces

Comment: Does it not compile because you mention casting it to SalesReceipt but inherited from SalesTransaction?

Comment: @tony oops.. that was a typo.

Comment: @Nkosi: I have read about contravariance, covariance and invariance and the conclusion that I came to is no - I can't simply using casting in this case. But I'm hoping that I'm wrong or someone has a trick up their sleeve that may help me workaround this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `SalesTransaction` repository as wrapper around repositories of more specific types. (Shown here for invoices)

```
public class InvoiceAsSalesTransactionRepository : IRepostory<SalesTransaction>
{
    private readonly IRepostory<Invoice> _invoiceRepository = new InvoiceRepository();

    public void Add(SalesTransaction item)
    {
        if (item is Invoice invoice) {
            _invoiceRepository.Add(invoice);
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException("Item must be Invoice");
        }
    }

    public SalesTransaction First(Expression<Func<SalesTransaction, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _invoiceRepository.First(ToInvoicePredicate(predicate));
    }

    public SalesTransaction Single(Expression<Func<SalesTransaction, bool>> predicate,
                                   bool disableTracking = false)
    {
        return _invoiceRepository.Single(ToInvoicePredicate(predicate), disableTracking);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> ToInvoicePredicate(
        Expression<Func<SalesTransaction, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Invoice), predicate.Parameters[0].Name);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Invoice, bool>>(predicate.Body, param);
    }
}
```

As you can see, you need some Reflection magic to convert the predicate type.  Therefore, you cannot simply cast your repositories. Note that we don't need to cast anything here, since a valid `SalesTansaction` predicate is always a valid `Invoice` predicate, as `SalesTansaction`s contain only properties also available in `Invoices`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be honest, it's not the kind of answer that I was expecting. I can't create a wrapper for each repository, let alone override each method in the repository.